# Location of pinned website in windows 8

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8, modern-ui

I'm currently developing a software and a website for a job.

The software and the website runs on Windows 8 tablet. We need to create a tile in the start menu for the software and the website.

It's easy to set a tile for the software during the installation process, by creating a shortcut and send it to `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs`.

But for a website how can I create the tile during the installation process and send it to the start menu?

Thanks.

Comment: You don't; it's up to the user to decide whether they want your Web site on their Start menu. They can pin it themselves from IE. (Or you could make an app that they can install from the Windows Store, that's just a thin wrapper around your Web site; but then the app wouldn't work when the tablet isn't connected to the Internet, and the store guidelines might frown on that, I'm not sure.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A website is not a application that you run on your local computer. 
It is the users choice if the wants to pin your website to the startmenu.

BUT there is something that you can do.

Remind the user to pin the site, and help him to pin it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg491729(v=vs.85).aspx

OR (worse)

Create a simple Windows 8 Store application in which there is not more than a Webcontrol with the website and a Privacy policy. This App will pin to start at W8.0 at install, keep in mind this is not working with W8.1. I do not advise this!